# Resolve IP Address of microservice instance in spring could [jhipster]

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, netflix-eureka

I am using Jhipster to create a simple microservices architectures, basically I have an Eureka registry running,to whom a bunch of microservices instances are registered.

Some microservices need to talk to other microservices or query some data, but each microservice has a dynamic IP address, is it possible to use the instanse name to resolve IP and do the request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already provided by the JHipster Eureka architecture.

- The microservices (Eureka clients) register with the registry (Eureka server).
- Then, each microservice that sets the `eureka.client.fetch-registry` property to `true` gets its  Ribbon instance configured and can connect to other registered services using service name URL like `http://<service name>/api/something` using a `RestTemplate` or a `FeignClient`

You did not say what kind of authentication you chose, this doc is for UAA and it might help even for plain JWT: https://www.jhipster.tech/using-uaa/#inter-service-communication

Answer (score 0):

You can use **server side load balancing** pattern. **Netflix Zuul** as API gateways offers you that kind of balancing (use **Netflix Ribbon** as load balancer).
In your case: create Zuul µservice (don't forget annotation`@EnableZuulProxy`) and register it in Eureka.

After these steps you'll be able to call your µservice instances registred in Eureka via Zuul µservice address without knowing their addresses on the client side.